# Apply flex-wrap to children even if only one wraps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider following example:
[image]

Each of these "items" (Name + price) has following structure:

```
<div class="product-customize-variant__row">
  <div class="product-customize-variant__name">
    {{name}}
  </div>
  <div class="product-customize-variant__price">
    £{{price}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `product-customize-variant__row` is `flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` and `flex-direction: row`.

As you can see, in second item (Soft Grained Calfskin), due to `flex-wrap` property price jumps to separate row can causes this mess.

My question is: Can I somehow force all other items to perform something like "force jump price to next line IF one of siblings wraps"?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on your markup. But if you want the price below the name. Change flex-direction value to column.

Comment: I want to keep price inline when it's possible. When it's not I'd like to wrap all children, even if only one doesn't fit.

Comment: Not possible with flexbox. Flexbox (and any other layout method) cannot affect the layout in sibling elements. You need javascript.